# Spotlight / Indicator-Synapse alternative for Windows

Tags: windows

I tried Linux for a while, but for my own reasons I've turned again to Windows 8.1

One of the tools I really love in Linux was the Indicator-Synapse. A search bar in the taskbar with great functionality. I think Mac has also a similar one called Spotlight.

I am looking for something similar for Windows in the taskbar.

What I like in the Indicator-Synapse and I love to have:

- Applications search in my pc
- Files search in my pc
- Google search
- Google maps search
- Wolfram search

You can find more information about them [here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/09/spotlight-like-tool-coming-to-pear-os-other-distros)

[image]

Comment: Hit the `Windows` logo key on your keyboard and start typing. It searches apps, documents and settings.